# Receiving unstructured JSON files in Spring Resources

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Currently I have a Resource as follows

```
@PostMapping("/color")
public String addColorData(@RequestBody Object obj){
    System.out.println(obj.toString());
    return "200";
}
```

and when I POST the JSON bellow

{
"color" : "Green",
"mixutres" : {
"Yellow" : 0.5,
"random2" : 0.5
}
}

the print is as expected - {color=Green, mixutres={Yellow=0.5, random2=0.5}}

However,

When I make a class Color

```
public class Color  {

    private String color;

    private Object mixtures;


    public Object getMixtures() {
        return mixtures;
    }

    public void setMixtures(Object mixtures) {
        this.mixtures = mixtures;
    }
```

and modify my Resource as bellow

```
@PostMapping("/color")
public String addColorData(@RequestBody Color colorObj){
    System.out.println(colorObj.toString());
    return "200";
}
```

mixtures ends up as 'null'

{color=Green, mixtures='null'}

1. Why does mixtures end up as 'null'?
2. Assuming that I don't know the exact structure of mixtures, is setting the Mixtures' type as Object the right approach? If not, could you guys give me some advice for best practices?

Thank you

--- Follow up --

Thanks to Gulliva found a typo in my JSON, when I tested after the edit

Spring returned the following

> trace":
> "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
> JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String`
> out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
> deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token\n
> at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 5, column: 18] (through
> reference chain:
>
> ....
> "message": "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
> deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token\n
> at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 5, column: 18] (through
> reference chain:

Comment: can you show getters and setters

Comment: Can you please add the mixtures class?

Answer (score 1):

If your structure is just key pair value then you can use Map<String, String> mixtures which is my preferred ds and your class would look like this :

```
public class Color  {

private String color;

private Map<String, String> mixtures;


public Map<String,String> getMixtures() {
    return mixtures;
}

public void setMixtures(Map<String,String> mixtures) {
    this.mixtures = mixtures;
}
```

As by taking collection type of structure would be helpful in future as well for data accessing/modifying.

Answer (score 0):

If your example at top is correct, then you have a Typo in the key "mixtures".

One suggestions here. Consider to use ResponseBody to as your ResponseEntity. Since ResponseBody is a generic class you can use it with the type you like and set a HTTP StatusCode like

`ResponseEntity.ok("hello world);`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo ! after changing it ended up with another issue :(